# Nested query is so slow in MySQL. How to optimize it?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have a table hall_products with products. Each product has a NAME, is sold in specified QUANTITY and only to one city pointed by CITY_CODE.
Now next table is delivery_address. Every delivery address is a city, it contains a CITY_CODE and MAX_QUANTITY that is a maximum quantity of a product that can be sent to this city (no matter what product).

So for example I have a product Milk with quantity 1 liter and addressed to the city with code 14 that means Berlin. 
And maximum quantity of good i can send to Berlin (city code 14) is 0,7 liter. Than i get ship the Milk to Berlin because quantity is higher than max_quantity.

What i want to get is names of all goods that can be shipped anywhere to the world. So i need to get all goods that fit into max_quantity limit of the target city.

And i wrote this query for this:

```
SELECT p.NAME FROM hall_products as p where p.QUANTITY >
 (SELECT MAX_QUANTITY from delivery_address WHERE CITY_CODE = p.CITY_CODE )
```

But this query is sooo slow.

How to make it faster without database schema change aka only with change of query?

Comment: Can you add output of explain.

Comment: Is that the query you actually use? It seems like a weird query to me.. the double `from` in the nested query and the `*` make it seem like it wouldn't work that well...

Comment: The query will not run at all. It is not allowed to return more than one column in the sub-select when using the `>` operator against it (actually I think it is never possible in MySQL to return more than one column in a subselect in MySQL)

Comment: Not only the query will not run, the example is also wrong: _product Milk with quantity 1 liter_ ... _And maximum quantity of good i can send to Berlin (city code 14) is 0,7 liter. Than i get ship the Milk to Berlin because quantity is lower than max_quantity_ I'm voting down.

Comment: @gnur, @a_horse_with_no_name - there was a mistake in query, now it's ok.

Comment: @Clodoaldo Yeah, it's correct now, and it should be "higher" not "lower". Corrected. thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general scenarios joins are considered to be better than nested queries. But there are scenarios where a nested query may perform better than joins.

Try this query and compare the results.

```
SELECT p.NAME 
FROM hall_products as p, delivery_address as d 
where p.QUANTITY < d.MAX_QUANTITY and d.CITY_CODE = p.CITY_CODE
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT p.NAME 
FROM hall_products as p, delivery_address as d 
where p.QUANTITY > d.MAX_QUANTITY and d.CITY_CODE = p.CITY_CODE
```

This will work fine again if you have indexes on QUANTITY and CITY_CODE

Answer (score 0):

> So i need to get all goods that fit into max_quantity limit of the target city.

Fit into means `<=` in my books, but I'm not on maths.se, so maybe you know something I don't.

A sub-query may be run for each-row of the result, it is normally slower than creating a JOIN.  Here's a JOIN in ANSI syntax

```
SELECT p.NAME
FROM hall_products p
JOIN delivery_address a on a.CITY_CODE = p.CITY_CODE
where p.QUANTITY <= a.MAX_QUANTITY
```